# Restricted Representation of the Quaternion Group

Tags: group-theory, characters

I want to determine the branching rules from the quaternion group to the group of the fourth roots of $1$. I have produced the character tables for the groups:

[image: Quaternion Group]

$$\text{The Quaternion Group}$$

and

[image: Fourth roots of one]

$$\text{The Fourth Roots of }1.$$

I am just self-learning restricted representations, and I haven't come across a problem like this one yet. I have learned that when you restrict a representation, you remove all of the group elements from the group which do not exist in the subgroup. Thus, for the group of the quaternions, we remove the two classes $\{j,-j\}$ and $\{k,-k\}$. Notice, however, that the group of the quaternions then has $3$ classes while the group of the fourth roots of $1$ has $4$ classes. To determine the relationship between the irreducible representations of a group and its subgroup, I've always used the orthogonality of rows in a character table, but I cannot apply this because the orthogonality principle requires that I have an equal number of columns (classes).

Perhaps this character table approach has limitations and cannot be applied in this case? Or perhaps there is a clever method to resolve the issue that I am facing. Thanks for your help.

As aside on notation:

1. I do not often see the gamma notation used on the stack exchange. In the textbook to which I refer (*Group Theory and Quantum Mechanics* by Michael Tinkham) it is common notation to denote the respresentation of a group element $A$ as $\Gamma(A)$ and thus the irreps are written $\Gamma^{(i)}$ for short.
2. My classes for the fourth roots on one are not contained within braces, I'm sorry.

Comment: The reason you get the wrong number is that you don't just "remove" elements. You need the columns to correspond to conjugacy clases, so you may need to split some of them up further upon restriction, as the elements might no longer be conjugate in the subgroup (you might also have run into other problems than this, where some of the conjugacy classes could have only some of their elements in the subgroup, but since the subgroup is normal here that does not happen).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft So I must split up the conjugacy class containing $\{i,-i\}$. Does that mean I simply duplicate the column (as in, the two split up conjugacy classes have identical columns in the restricted-representation character table, equal to the column from the initial character table)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by the restricted-representation character table. We usually only make a table like this out of the irreducible representations.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft There is a method for determining the branching rules of a particular group to its subgroup by removing all elements in the group that do not belong to the subgroup, and then removing the empty columns in the original character table. You then use the orthogonality of rows between the character table of the subgroup and this newly generated character table to determine which of the representations of the group are reducible when restricted to the subgroup.

Comment: What do you mean by the orthogonality between rows of different tables? Once you have the character table of the subgroup and the characters of the restricted representations, you can just compute all the inner products to determine branching.

Comment: I think we're discussing the same thing. And I think that answers my question.